# Passing argument to ActionListener from Object

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
public class start implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL) {
      method(arguments);

    }
  }

method(arguments) {
   //stuff
}
```

I want a JButton to tell the program to start a method using the arguments "stuff" So I put the actionListener above on the button however the actionListener does not have access to the arguments and I don't know how to give it them (I looked at the oracle docs and couldn't figure it out). I tried this:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent aL, stuff) {
```

and that doesn't work, I get the error

```
Compute.java:45: error: Compute.start is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
  public class start implements ActionListener {
         ^
```

And I tried putting an @Override but you can't override that according to the compiler. So, how can I give the arguments to the ActionListener or have the method outside of the button but only start working once the button is pressed, however I am using a JProgressBar within the JFrame the button is in which uses the method as it's timer thing so it would be preferable to pass the arguments to the actionListener

Also, above is the action Listener, outside of that is the object with the button that uses the actionListener:

```
//imports
public class someObject extends JFrame {
//attributes
public someObject() {

//blah blah

go = new JButton("Compute!");

start c = new start();
    go.addActionListener(c);
```

So yea basically how do I pass arguments from the Object to the ActionListener?

Comment: You don't pass the arguments - the signature of `actionPerformed()` must match the one defined in the `ActionListener` interface, as you have found out. You can 1. obtain the additional data by calling a method of the `someObject` (or alternatively reading a field directly, if the action listener is an internal class). 2. if the data is known at the time of the creation of the action listener, you can use a local final (or effectively final in java 8) variable for an anonymous listener, or pass it as a constructor parameter if you prefer a named listener.

Comment: Your someObject JFrame should  implements ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

```
public class someObject extends JFrame {
// attributes
public someObject() {

    // blah blah

    JButton bt = new JButton("Compute!");
    int obj = 4;
    start c = new start((Object)obj);
    bt.addActionListener(c);
    this.add(bt);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    someObject so = new someObject();

    so.setVisible(true);
}
}

class start implements ActionListener {

private Object paramObj;

public start(Object param) {
    this.paramObj = param;
    if(param==null)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Param is null");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent al) {
    method(paramObj);
}

private void method(Object obj) {
    // stuff
    if(obj!=null)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Method has been called successfully! obj="+ String.valueOf(obj));
}
}
```